# Set height and width of divs in px or percentage so it looks the same in all resolutions?

Tags: html, css

If I want my website to look the same on many different screen sizes and want my divs to all be the same height and width regardless of if it's on a 11 inch macbook or a 27 inch monitor.

Do I set my height and width in pixels or in percentages in my CSS?

I'm guessing percentages, but just want to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on exactly what you mean by "same height".  If you want something to always take the full width of the page regardless of resolution, use `100%`.  If you want something to always take `x` number of pixels, specify in `px`.  If you want something to use relative sizing so that as fonts get bigger, everything scales, then use `ems`.

As it is worded, your question and intent isn't clear.  You should decide what it is you want to do and then implement it.

Web development is about making content usable in a variety of formats and sizes.  Consider why you want a fixed size, and work to achieve your goals within the constraints of CSS.  And remember, you can always mix metrics if you need to.

Comment: let me be clearer. I'm workign on a laptop that's 1440 x 900. I want a "contact us" box that is 375px in height. Now, if someone else on a much larger screen and different resolution, wouldn't that change the appearance on their screen? In other words would the div be the same height regardless? I guess I'm not certain how resolutions and pixels work with different screen sizes

Comment: @StackOverflow If you have a size measured in pixels, it will always in pixels (virtual viewport sizes and zooming aside).  `375px` is `375px` everywhere.  Now, the size of the pixel certainly does change from device to device, as does the the number of them.  It isn't clear to me what you mean by "same height".  Same height in what dimension?  Are you referring to physical size?  Meters and inches?